# How to add custom Semigroup instance for Int

Tags: scala, scala-cats, semigroup

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._

object SemigroupInstances {
  implicit val intSemigroup: Semigroup[Int] = new Semigroup[Int] {
    override def combine(a: Int, b: Int) = a * b
  }
}

import SemigroupInstances._

object Semigroup {
  def apply[T](implicit instance: Semigroup[T]): Semigroup[T] = instance
}

val intSemigroup = Semigroup[Int]

intSemigroup.combine(4, 4) // expected 16, actual 8
```

So, how to make custom `intSemigroup` working?

Comment: You import two instances of `Semigroup[Int]` - one via `import cats.implicits._`, one via `import SemigroupInstances._`. Apparently, the compiler choose the one from `import cats.implicits._` over your custom instance. If you remove that import, it works: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/avsmEturTRGkNEOCDxuXOA

Comment: If removing that import is not an option for you, you might want to look into the details of implicit resolution precedence. I'm sure there are ways to ensure that your instance given higher precedence.

Comment: @MartinHH Appreciate your help. Post please an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Is this in the REPL?  The REPL has some implementation details (compilation units and such) which sometimes mess up implicit search.

Comment: @LeviRamsey, no, this is from Scala Worksheet

Comment: @LeshaPipiev I posted an answer now. I did not really want to answer without understanding why the compiler chooses the instance from cats over your instance, but I figured that out now as well (see bottom part of the answer).

Comment: For reference, a more idiomatic way to solve this is by using a newtype around int to drive selection of different instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You import two instances of `Semigroup[Int]`:

1. via `import cats.implicits._`
2. via `import SemigroupInstances._`

The compiler chooses the one from `cats.implicits._` over your custom instance.

If you remove that import, it works: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/avsmEturTRGkNEOCDxuXOA

If you want to know more about how the compiler chooses which implicit instance to use, see this post: [Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits/5598107#5598107)

In your specific case, the reason appears to be that the type of [the instance from cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/bf3547357b1641b73b72efbcfe3674be806be3db/kernel/src/main/scala/cats/kernel/instances/IntInstances.scala#L28) is actually `CommutativeGroup[Int]`:

```
implicit val catsKernelStdGroupForInt: CommutativeGroup[Int] = new IntGroup
```

Hence, being a derived class (`CommutativeGroup` extends `Semigroup`), it is considered more specific and hence preferred.

If you change the type of your instance to `CommutativeGroup[Int]` (which is not possible without being mathematically incorrect, but that's not the point here), you get an "Ambiguous given instances" error because the compiler cannot decide which instance to use: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/dzClDOYDSJ20P1SRpH72nA